# HTML Email Outlook.com lines appearing under column

Tags: html-email, outlook.com

In my email design I have strange lines appearing under my right hand column.  The left hand column seems uneffected.  It appears to be the styling from my `<a>` (the link).

The links don't appear to be linking either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by using `<a href="#">` or by not using `http://` or `https://`.  I replaced all `"#"` with `"http://www.example.com"` to resolve.

This was causing my border from my link to show on my column.  So if you see other link styling on your column, or a `<td>` that could be why